# Several web process types in Heroku

Tags: heroku

A single Rails app running in Heroku receives the requests in two subdomains: api.domain.com and www.domain.com.

As per [Heroku's Procfile documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) there is only one process type that receives the http requests (that is called "web").

Is it possible to create a second "web" process so I can scale independently the number of dynos for the 2 subdomains (for example, giving more dynos to the API subdomain).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that - only the `web` process receives traffic, you can't have more than 1 in an app.

You could deploy the same code to 2 Heroku apps and run one on www and the other on api.